# What is this threading code doing?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was trying to understand what does this module threading I have seen this code and I didn't know what this line `t = threading.Thread(target=worker)` is supposed to mean. Please any one can help me?

How can this threading help?

```
import threading

def worker():        
    print 'Worker'
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: thank you sir but i need to know if there is a way to avoid using this module on a script like this

Comment: Creates a `Thread` object referred to by the name `t`.

Comment: can't we just call the function on the for loop with out using the threading because i have the same resulte when i call the Worker() func on the for loop

Comment: You ask if you can avoid using `threading`:  this is such a trivial example that there is very little point in using it.   Where does the code come from, why are you using it, and why don't you want to use `threading`?

Comment: i was reading hacking book and i have seen this module and i wan to learn more about it

Comment: In that case is was probably just a simple example to demonstrate threading.  I doubt it was meant as a useful slice of code.  I suggest you keep studying.

Comment: thank you for your time i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the threading target is 'worker' function.

Here is another example.

```
import threading

def example(argv_0):
    print argv_0


th = threading.Thread(target=example, args=('hi',))
th.start()
th.join()
```

This means that the thread target is example with an argument 'hi'.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer i think i have to read more about this module

Comment: sorry sir you are right next this mistake will not being repeated